# python-requests auth 405 error and AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-requests, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use python "requests" module to access SECURE NIFI rest API (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/). Till now, I face 2 problems:

1. I tried to use basic and digest authentication methods provided by
   “requests” module to login into secure NIFI (with OpenLDAP), but it
   gives me the “400” status code. So, I
   had to pass “username and password” in HEADERS of the request to get
   the user token.
2. When I try to pass the obtained token to further
   requests:

(e.g., `pg_resp=requests.get("https://localhost:9443/nifi-api/process-groups/2be8231f-015b-1000-47b1-428fc8c594e1",
headers="Authorization: Bearer <auth_code>")`),

it gives me this error “AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'”. I tried to change 'unicode' to string, but 'string' also has no attribute 'items'

The traceback for both 'unicode' is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 295, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 407, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The traceback for 'str' is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 295, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/home/shambakey1/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 407, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass headers as a `dict` to the `requests.get()` method:

```
pg_resp=requests.get(
    "https://localhost:9443/nifi-api/process-groups/2be8231f-015b-1000-47b1-428fc8c594e1",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <auth_code>"}
)
```

The requests module is attempting to unpack your string as a dict (calling `items()` on it) and neither `str` nor `unicode` have such method, hence the error.